# How to change the sampling time in OMNeT++?

Tags: omnet++, sampling, inet

Is there a way to change the sampling time of recording in OMNeT++?
For example, when I record something using vector-recording at the end of a parameter in the .ini file, the program will record data with a certain sampling time, and I'd like to change it.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as sampling a value in OMNeT++. Whenever a value is changed (and the value is recorded) its new value is immediately written out to the vector file along with the current timestamp. You immediately see when a value changes and its value will remain the same until it changes next time.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Would you mind checking my other questions?